# Set constraint on type family in GHC 8

Tags: haskell, type-constraints, type-families

Suppose I have the following code:

```hs
class Eq (Foo a) => Bar a where
    type Foo a :: *

doSmth:: Proxy a -> Foo a -> Bool
doSmth _ a = a == a
```

In GHC 7 it works fine, but GHC 8 complains:

```
• No instance for (Eq (Foo a)) arising from a use of ‘==’
• In the expression: a == a
  In an equation for ‘doSmth’: doSmth _ a = a == a
```

How can I say that `Foo a` is always instance of `Eq`?

Comment: Why not just have `doSmth :: Eq (Foo a) => Proxy a -> Foo a -> Bool`? Furthermore, with your current definition for `Bar`, you could even have `doSmth :: Bar a => Proxy a -> Foo a -> Bool`...

Comment: FTR, this does _not_ work in GHC-7.10.2. (In fact I'm surprised that it ever worked at all.) `Foo` doesn't actually pack any constraints, these come all from the `Bar` class head (which `Foo` doesn't have access to). — If you have these constraints hidden under existential quantification (GADTs, I presume) then what's the problem unpacking them with a GADT case pattern match?

Comment: Somehow, when I extracted `Foo a` from `GADT`, constaint `Bar a` got lost (although I had this constraint in GADT type). But after some magic at GADT extraction site it became working, I've no idea why )  Thanks for help ^^